# calling a function on another fuction in the same file

Tags: c

i have an error massage but i don't undestand what is the problem. i'm deperately searching for the problem.
i tried to create a libary function, and include one of the function on another function in the same file. Is this posibble ? if so please expalain.

```
  #include "head.h"

void fungsiCetak()
{
    int i,n;
    system("cls");
    system("color 1f");
    FILE*nip,*nama,*golongan,*anak,*kk,*birth;
    nip=fopen("nip.txt","a");
    nama=fopen("nama.txt","a");
    anak=fopen("jum_anak.txt","a");
    kk=fopen("jum_kk.txt","a");
    birth=fopen("birth.txt","a");
    golongan=fopen("golongan.txt","a");
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Berapa data yang ingin di inputkan ? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    i=1;
do{
        fflush(stdin);
        printf(" Masukan NIP               : ");
        gets(pegawai.nip);
        fprintf(nip,"%s\n",pegawai.nip);
        printf("Masukan nama Pegawai       : ");
        gets(pegawai.nama);
        fprintf(nama,"%s\n",pegawai.nama);
        printf("Masukan golongan           : ");
        scanf("%d",&pegawai.gol);
        fprintf(golongan,"%d\n",pegawai.gol);
        printf("Jumlah anak                : ");
        scanf("%d",&pegawai.jum_anak);
        fprintf(anak,"%d\n",pegawai.jum_anak);
        printf("Jumlah anggota keluarga    : ");
        scanf("%d",&pegawai.jum_kk);
        fprintf(kk,"%d\n",pegawai.jum_kk);
        printf("Tanggal lahir (dd-mm-yyyy) : ");
        scanf("%d-%d-%d",&pegawai.birth.hari,
                        &pegawai.birth.bulan,
                        &pegawai.birth.tahun);
        fprintf(birth,"%d-%d-%d\n",pegawai.birth.hari,
                        pegawai.birth.bulan,
                        pegawai.birth.tahun);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
} while(i<=n);

    fclose(nip);
    fclose(nama);
    fclose(golongan);
    fclose(anak);
    fclose(kk);
    fclose(birth);
}
void fungsiBaca()
{
    system("cls");
    int count=0;
    int nip2,nip1[20],anak1[20],kk1[20];
    int gol[20];
    char birth1[30][30];
    char bufer[100],buffer1[100];
    char nama1[30][30];

    struct pegawai;
    FILE*nip,*nama,*golongan,*anak,*kk,*birth;
    nama=fopen("nama.txt","r");
        i=0;
        while(fgets(bufer,sizeof bufer,nama)!=NULL)
        {
            strcpy(nama1[i],bufer);
            i++;
        }
        a=0;
    golongan=fopen("golongan.txt","r");
        while(a<=i)
        {
          fscanf(golongan,"%d",&gol[a]);
          a++;
        }
    nip=fopen("nip.txt","r");
        a=0;
        while(a<i)
            {
              fscanf(nip,"%d",&nip1[a]);
                a++;
            }
    anak=fopen("jum_anak.txt","r");
        a=0;
        while(a<i)
        {
            fscanf(anak,"%d",&anak1[a]);
            a++;
        }
    kk=fopen("jum_kk.txt","r");
        a=0;
        while(a<i)
        {
            fscanf(kk,"%d",&kk1[a]);
            a++;
        }
    birth=fopen("birth.txt","r");
        a=0;
       while(fgets(buffer1,sizeof buffer1,birth)!=NULL)
       {
           strcpy(birth1[a],buffer1);
           a++;
       }
search :
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    printf("masukan NIP : ");
    scanf("%d",&nip2);
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    for(a=0; a<=i; a++)
    {
        if(nip1[a]==nip2){
            printf("Nama pegawai  : %s",nama1[a]);
            printf("Golongan      : %d\n",gol[a]);
            printf("Jumlah anak   : %d\n",anak1[a]);
            printf("Jumlah KK     : %d\n",kk1[a]);
            printf("Tanggal Lahir : %s\n",birth1[a]);
            count=1;
        }
    }
    if (count==0)
        {
          printf("Maaf data tidak ditemukan!\n");
        }
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingin mencari data kembali ? [y/n]");
    scanf("%c",&kembali);
    if (kembali=='y')
        {
            system("cls");
            goto search;
        }
    fclose(nip);
    fclose(nama);
    fclose(golongan);
    fclose(kk);
    fclose(anak);
    fclose(birth);
}
void fungsiGaji ()
{
    int gol,absen;
    float tunj_makan,tunj_anak,tunj_kes,total,gajih_pokok;
    fungsiBaca();
//////////////////////////////////////////////////Kondisi gajih pokok
    if (gol[a]==1)
    {
        gajih_pokok=GOl1;
    } else if (gol[a]==2)
    {
        gajih_pokok=GOL2;
    } else if (gol[a]==3)
    {
        gajih_pokok=GOl3;
    } else
    {
        gajih_pokok=GOL4;
    }
    printf("Gajih pokok : %.2f",gajih_pokok);
/////////////////////////////////////////////// kondisi tunjangan

}
```

the error message is
[image: i] I use CodeBlocks to create the program

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should declare all your function `void xxx (void)` instead of `void xxx ()`

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: `gol` is not an array so you cannot do `if (gol[a] == 1)` and so on...

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is not doing what you think it is -- and it can invoke *undefined behavior* on a number of platforms. Best to avoid it. See the notes in `man fflush`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int gol,absen; <--- gol is integer
...
if (gol[a]==1) <---- gol[a] ?
```